# How to add format to an input of unformatted numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to ask an user to input an unformatted telephone number like: 1234567890
and then later output it as (123)=456-7890

How would you do that in Python 3?

I know how to use if else statements and while/for loops, but not how to import modules.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use `.format()`. First of all, everything that comes in using `input()` comes in as a string, and as such can be spliced. I would do something like this.

```
raw = input("Enter your unformatted phone number:")
if len(raw) != 10:
    raise Exception("Phone number must be 10 digits long")
formatted = "({0})-{1}-{2}".format(raw[:3], raw[3:6], raw[-4:])
```

The `.format()` function is a method of the string class, and it takes in positional (or keyword) arguments. In this case, it takes the token `{0}` and replaces it with the first argument to `.format()` (remember everything in python is zero-indexed).

Now let's take a look at the arguments being passed to the format method. Let's say the phone number inputted by the user is `raw = "1234567890"`.
Because this is a string, we can splice it the same way we could a list. `raw[:3]` grabs the first three elements of the iterable, `raw[3:6]` grabs the fourth to sixth elements of the iterable, and `raw[-4]` grabs the last four elements.

So, if you were to `print(formatted)` you would get something like `(123)-456-7890`.

Comment: thank you! do you mind explaining this? formatted = "({0})-{1}-{2}".format(raw[:3], raw[3:6], raw[-4:])?

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated the answer to explain the format syntax and the splicing syntax